# Anyone know of a replacement for simplepagination?

Tags: pagination

On our site we've been using simplepagination (http://www.vayadesign.net/software/simple-pagination/release-notes) which lets us specify a page break by merely inserting {pagebreak} into the body of a post.

However this plug-in seems to have stopped working in the EE 2.7.x and the developer is no longer working on it.

Has anyone found an alertnative?

Comment: Can you update your question to describe the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look into this and couldn't find any replacement. I suggest you to go with the [default solution](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/pagination_spanning.html). It doesn't do everything you want to, but is better than keep all your system outdated.

I'm sorry.